# NavController's pop and back don't go back to previous page as expected

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 4 with Angular. I have this page that, only on certain conditions that I managed to reproduce, behaves weirdly when going back to previous page.
If I call`this.navCtrl.pop();` it goes back to the main page instead of the previous one, if I call `this.navCtrl.back();` it goes back to the previous page, but calls its contructor again and the router doesn't have the initial extras anymore, so it's impossible to really initialize the page again.

Basically, if we name the pages A, B, C etc the flow that always produces this issue is:

*A(main page) -> B -> C -> D -> B , this is where I press back and expect D back.*

A working flow:

*A -> C -> D -> B, then back*

Even if I chain the 2 of them, but start with the working one, everything is fine.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug?

Comment: I guess that when you're pushing B the second time it's actually making the first instance of B to be the active page (since that route already exists in the navigation history) but I'm not really sure why. Could you please create a stackblitz with your code so we can take a look at it? (you can fork [this demo project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64790924?file=src/app/app.component.ts) if you want)